# Representing some odd multiples of integral homology classes by embedded submanifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, cohomology, homology

Consider an $m$-dimensional compact closed orientable smooth manifold $M$ and an $n$-dimensional integral homology class $[\Sigma]$ on $M$, with $1 \le n \le m-1$. Then does there exist an odd integer $\nu$ (which is allowed to depend on $n, m, [\Sigma],M,$) such that $\nu[\Sigma]$ can be represented by a smoothly embedded compact submanifold (not necessarily connected)? If $[\Sigma]$ is of odd-torsion, then we regard this as formally true.

I'm aware of Thom's work on representing homology classes. In the case of the Steenrod problem, i.e., representing homology classes by maps from manifolds, it is often mentioned that some odd multiple of a class can always be represented, and there are plenty of references.

For representation by embedded submanifolds, when $2n<m,$ a generic perturbation of any realizing map solving the Steenrod problem can yield an embedded submanifold, so some odd multiple suffices. However, I do not know how to deal with the case of $2n\ge m$. Due to my limited knowledge, I do not know if my question follows from Thom's work.

I'm sorry if this is a trivial question, as I work in geometric measure theory, which is very far away from algebraic topology. Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can in general do this. I think you can do this for $n=m-1$, and $m-2$. This is probably also in Thom's paper.  The poincare dual of the class $H_{n-1}(M)$ is represented by a map $M\rightarrow S^1$. The preimage of a regular value should be a representing submanifold. For $n=m-2$ you take a map $M\rightarrow CP^\infty$ representing the dual cohomology class. Then use cellular approximation to map $M$ to $CP^N$ for some large $N$, and take the preimage of $CP^{N-1}$ after perturbing the map to meet this submanifold transversally.

Comment: I think Mark Grant answers your question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375919/can-every-element-of-a-homotopy-group-of-a-smooth-manifold-be-represented-by-an

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Maybe you misunderstood my question? I've cleared up it a bit. I'm asking for just one odd multiple that can be represented by some embedded submanifold, and this is known to hold for $2n<m$. I'm just seeking to understand the case of $2n\ge m.$ To my limited knowledge, Mark Grant's excellent answer deals with immersions from spheres, instead of embeddings of all possible manifolds.

Comment: You are right, i was too quick

Comment: No problem at all! I'm really glad to receive comments. Mark Grant's conclusion is really surprising, and I didn't notice that question before.

Comment: Are you aware of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.0249.pdf . This shows that there are homology classes which cannot be represented by immersed, let alone embedded, manifolds. This is with Z_2 coefficients, but presumably this can be used in the integer coefficient case as well.

Comment: Good question. Here is an observation which might be used to produce counter-examples: Suppose $x$ is a mod 2 cohomology class which is not realizable by a submanifold, and such that $x$ admits an integral lift $\tilde{x}$. Then no odd multiple of $\tilde{x}$ is realizable by an oriented submanifold.

Comment: This is because if $\nu\tilde{x}$ were so realizable, then its mod 2 reduction $x$ would also be realizable. I think it's conceivable that such classes $x$ exist, in high enough dimensions. It suffices to find a class in $H^*(K(\mathbb{Z}/2,k);\mathbb{Z}/2)$ which is in the kernel of the map induced by the Thom class $MO(k)\to K(\mathbb{Z}/2,k)$ and also in the kernel of the Bockstein to integral cohomology.

Comment: I don't have the bandwidth to do the calculations right now. Regarding the paper with Szucs that @ThomasRot mentioned: since we were interested in non-realizability by immersions, we were only able to use *stable* cohomology operations. For embeddings any operation can be used (e.g. $\iota Sq^1\iota + Sq^2 Sq^1\iota$) which makes things a bit easier.

Comment: Many thanks for the comments! That looks promising! I'll try to do the exercises.